# How to get nearest divide by 100 number in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a new column in pandas dataframe based on input column. Newly added column must be populated like this.

1. first row must be populated with nearest divide by 100 number.
2. from next row onwards output will be repeated until its difference with input value is more than or equal to 100.

   ```
   input       output
   11700.15    11700
   11695.20    11700
   11661.00    11700
   11630.40    11700
   11666.10    11700
   11600.30    11700
   11600.00    11600
   11555.40    11600
   11655.20    11600
   11699.00    11600
   11701.55    11700
   11799.44    11700
   11604.65    11700
   11600.33    11700
   11599.65    11600
   ```

what is the most elegant way to do this in pandas?

Comment: I do not think pandas can do this, maybe for loop

Comment: Your output is incorrect.  The last *two* rows should be 1600.  11600.33 is more than 100 away from 11701.55, where the run of 1700 starts

Comment: @user3483203 let's wait for OP but as I understood the question the important difference is the one between the previous output and the current input. So for the last two rows it's `(11700 - 11600.33) < 100` and `(11700 - 11599.65 > 100)`

Comment: @filippo Ah, I believe you're right.  It's a one character change in my answer so I'll add both alternatives

Comment: @user3483203, yes filippo is right. the difference is the one between the previous output and the current input. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there isn't an intuitive approach here that doesn't involve explicit iteration, which is not ideal for `numpy` and `pandas`.  However, the time complexity of this problem is O(n), which makes it a good target for the `numba` library.  This allows us to come up with a very efficient solution.

One note about my solution, I round using `(a + threshold // 2) // threshold * threshold`, which looks verbose compared to using `np.round(a, decimals=-2)`.  This is due to the nature of using `numba`'s `nopython=True`, flag, which is not compatible with the `np.round` function.

---

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def cumsum_with_threshold(arr, threshold):
       """
       Rounds values in an array, propogating the last value seen until
       a cumulative sum reaches a threshold
       :param arr: the array to round and sum
       :param threshold: the point at which to stop propogation
       :return: rounded output array
       """

       s = a.shape[0]
       o = np.empty(s)
       d = a[0]
       r = (a + threshold // 2) // threshold * threshold
       c = 0
       o[0] = r[0]

       for i in range(1, s):
           if np.abs(a[i] - d) > threshold:
               o[i] = r[i]
               d = a[i]
           else:
               o[i] = o[i - 1]

       return o
```

Let's test it out:

```
a = df['input'].values
pd.Series(cumsum_with_threshold(a, 100))
```

```
0     11700.0
1     11700.0
2     11700.0
3     11700.0
4     11700.0
5     11700.0
6     11600.0
7     11600.0
8     11600.0
9     11600.0
10    11700.0
11    11700.0
12    11700.0
13    11600.0
14    11600.0
dtype: float64
```

---

If you want to compare the *rounded* value with the input, instead of the *actual* value, simply make the following change to the function above in the loop, which gives the output from your question.

```
for i in range(1, s):
   if np.abs(a[i] - d) > t:
       o[i] = r[i]
       # OLD d = a[i]
       d = r[i]
   else:
       o[i] = o[i - 1]
```

---

To test the efficiency, let's run this on a much larger dataset:

```
l = np.random.choice(df['input'].values, 10_000_000)

%timeit cumsum_with_threshold(l, 100)
1.54 µs ± 7.93 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks user3483203. It worked as expected. I was interested in difference is between the previous output and the current input. Thanks a lot and highly appreciate your time and efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Not elegant by any means, but then I guess there's no way around a loop for this (could be wrong!):

```
vals = df1['input'].values
anchor = vals[0]
ch = np.zeros(len(vals))
ch.fill(np.nan)
for i in range(len(vals)):
    if abs(vals[i] - anchor) >= 100:
        anchor = vals[i]
        ch[i] = 1
    else:
        continue
ch[0] = 1

df['out_check'] = pd.Series(100* np.round((df['input'] * ch)/100)).ffill()
```

OUTPUT:

```
       input  output  out_check
0   11700.15   11700    11700.0
1   11695.20   11700    11700.0
2   11661.00   11700    11700.0
3   11630.40   11700    11700.0
4   11666.10   11700    11700.0
5   11600.30   11700    11700.0
6   11600.00   11600    11600.0
7   11555.40   11600    11600.0
8   11655.20   11600    11600.0
9   11699.00   11600    11600.0
10  11701.55   11700    11700.0
11  11799.44   11700    11700.0
12  11604.65   11700    11700.0
13  11600.33   11700    11600.0
14  11599.65   11600    11600.0
```

I do believe the last two values in `output` must be 1600.

Comment: Use `df['out_check'] = (df['input'] * ch).round(-2).ffill()` for your last line.  Much cleaner

Comment: @VishnuKunchur, Thanks man. Last 2 output is also correct.I was interested in difference is between the previous output and the current input. your solution helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with:

```
last = df.loc[0, 'input'].round(-2)
for ix in range(len(df)):
    inp = df.loc[ix, 'input']
    last = inp.round(-2) if abs(inp - last) >= 100 else last
    df.loc[ix, 'output'] = last
```

which produces exactly the output given by the OP.